# how to programatically uncheck the option "store only latest version property in VSS" for a project?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have an issue in VSS 2005, there is a project in VSS, having multiple folders files in it, and most of the files around 2000 having their property "Store only latest version" is checked.

I want to change all those 2000 files property "Store only latest version" to unchecked, so that VSS retain all those files previous version.

can it be done through a single command to unchecked this option for all those files in project recursively?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

User the command line utility **ss** with **properties** command and the **-L-** (unset Retain only latest version) and **-R** (recursive) like below

```
ss properties -L- -R $/foo/*.*
```

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/checkitout/archive/2005/01/20/357820.aspx

Note - for the command line utility to work you will need to set the SSDIR environment variable to point to your srcsafe.ini folder.

```
SET SSDIR=\\dirfoo\foo
```